# Salesforce Community - Knowledge Articles

Tags: community, knowledge, servicecloud, lightning-knowledge, topics

I have a Customer Community and I need to provide customers the ability to search knowledge articles based on model numbers and other types of information. So for example they can search a model of a product they own if they are having issues and receive suggested articles.

However I am unsure how to do so. I have provided topics per article but I would like to search articles via product model numbers. I am unsure if data category would solve my issue. Knowledge is not my strongest area so any help appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Yes, data categories are probably the best way to do this. You could then create a matching topic, and automatically assign the topic to articles with that data category in the content workspace.

I find the data category/topic system very cumbersome to use in Experience Cloud sites but there isn't a better alternative as far as I know.